# Using smtpjs to send the value of the form in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, smtp, smtpjs

I am trying to use [SmtpJS](https://smtpjs.com/) to capture the value of my form and send it to my email.

So far I have the following form markup:

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" />
  
  <input type="text" name="idea" placeholder="Idea" />

  <div class="fruits">
  <input type="checkbox" id="apple" name="apple" value="apple">
  <label for="apple"> Apple</label><br>
   <input type="checkbox" id="orange" name="orange" value="orange">
  <label for="orange"> Orange</label><br>
  </div>

  <div class="gender">
  <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
    <label for="male">Male</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
    <label for="female">Female</label><br>
 </div>

 <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick={() => sendEmail() }/>
    
</form>
```

I understand in order to use smtpjs, you first need to include it like this:

```
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js">
</script>
```

And then you need a function that will actually capture and send the email like this:

```
function sendEmail(){

    Email.send({
        Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
        Username : "username",
        Password : "password",
        To : 'them@website.com',
        From : "you@isp.com",
        Subject : "This is the subject",
        Body : "And this is the body"
    }).then(
      message => alert(message)
    );
    
    }
```

How do I capture the inputs `values`, `checked` checkbox and `selected` radio buttons values and include them on the body of my email that will send to my email?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using an `onClick` attribute on the `button`, I would use an event listener on the `submit` event of the `form`.  The `e.target` for this event is the `form` element itself so you can make use of the [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) object to access properties on your form by their `name` property.

You can create a `FormData` object from your event handler by using `const data = new FormData(e.target)` and then you can access properties like `data.get("fullname")`.  You can also use `data.get()` inside of a [Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to create texts like `Welcome ${data.get("fullname")}`.

```js
function sendEmail(to, subject, body){
  console.log("Sending Email:");
  console.log("Subject:\n", subject);
  console.log("Body:\n", body);
    Email.send({
        Host : "smtp.yourisp.com",
        Username : "username",
        Password : "password",
        To : to,
        From : "you@isp.com",
        Subject : subject,
        Body : body
    }).then(
      message => console.log(message)
    ); 
}

const form = document.getElementById("myform");
form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const data = new FormData(e.target);
  const subject = `Welcome ${data.get("fullname")}`;
  const fruits = [data.get("apple"), data.get("orange")].filter(fruit => fruit !== null);
  const body = `Your idea ${data.get("idea")} has been submitted. Your selections are ${fruits.join(" ")} ${data.get("gender")}.`;
  sendEmail("them@website.com", subject, body);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script>
<body>
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" />
  
  <input type="text" name="idea" placeholder="Idea" />

  <div class="fruits">
    <input type="checkbox" id="apple" name="apple" value="apple">
    <label for="apple"> Apple</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="orange" name="orange" value="orange">
    <label for="orange">Orange</label><br>
  </div>

  <div class="gender">
    <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male">
    <label for="male">Male</label><br>
    <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female">
    <label for="female">Female</label><br>
  </div>

 <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the script, you can include the following

```js
var apple_checked;
var orange_checked;
var male_checked;
var female_checked;

function getCheckedValues(){
if (document.getElementById('apple').checked) {
            apple_checked="isChecked!";
        }else{
apple_checked="notChecked:(";
}

if (document.getElementById('orange').checked) {
            orange_checked="isChecked!";
        }else{
orange_checked="notChecked:(";
}

if (document.getElementById('male').checked){
male_checked="isChecked!";
}else{
male_checked="notChecked:(";
}

if (document.getElementById('female').checked){
female_checked="isChecked!";
}else{
female_checked="notChecked:(";
}

}
```

Obviously, you will need to call the function `getCheckedValues()` somewhere.

Then, for the Body of your Email.Send(), you could set the following value (give ids of inputs for firstname and idea as id="firstname" and id="idea":

```js
Body : "First Name: "+document.getElementById('firstname').value+" Idea: "+document.getElementById('idea').value+"apple: "+apple_checked+" orange:"+orange_checked+" male: "+male_checked+" female: "+female_checked;
```